# Simple banking program with 2 methods that I can't quite resolve C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that has these two methods that I can't quite figure out. They are 'withdraw' and 'deposit' and they're located in the CheckingAccount class.  In these methods, I want to initially have the value be 0 then add to it. Then I want to take the new number and subtract from it. I want to 'deposit' 250 dollars. Then I want to 'withdraw' 98 dollars. I'm not sure where to store these values and how to execute them. I have how the display should look at the end of this while I left the withdraw and deposit methods empty.

Account Class:

```
class Account
{
    protected string firstName;
    protected string lastName;
    protected long number;

    public string FirstName
    {
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
        }
    }
    public long Number
    {
        set
        {
            number = value;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + "\nAccount #: " + number;
    }
}
}
```

Checking Account Class:

```
    class CheckingAccount : Account
{
    private decimal balance;

    public CheckingAccount(string firstName, string lastName, long number, decimal initialBalance)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Number = number;
        Balance = initialBalance;
    }
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return balance;
        }
        set
        {
            balance = value;
        }
    }


    public void deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        //initial value should be 0 and should be adding 250 to it.
    }
    public void withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        //this takes the 250 amount and subtracts 98 from it
    }


    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Balance: ${0}", Balance);
    }
}
}
```

Display class:

```
    class Display
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        CheckingAccount check = new CheckingAccount("John", "Smith", 123456, 0M);

        Console.WriteLine("After Account Creation...");
        check.display();

        Console.WriteLine("After Depositing $250...");
        //constructor
        Console.WriteLine("After Withdrawing $98...");
        //constructor
    }
}
}
```

I want my output to look like such:

After Account Creation...
  John Smith
  Account #: 123456
  Balance: 0

After Depositing $250...
  John Smith
  Account #: 123456
  Balance: 250

After Withdrawing $98...
  John Smith
  Account #: 123456
  Balance: 152

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is

```
public void deposit(decimal amount)
{
    balance += amount;
}
public void withdraw(decimal amount)
{
    balance -= amount;
}
```

Feel free to add the necessary validation (overdrawn? trying to deposit a negative amount?)

Comment: In a real-world scenario that you use databases, the objects in the memory could be out of sync with the database. So code like the above one doesn't protect the negative balance in a multi-thread situation (like a web or mobile app). It would cose the bank huge if hackers know that!
You should find a better pattern to protect your bank app!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to provide additional logic to the withdraw method to prevent overdrafting.

```
public void withdraw(decimal amount)
{
    if (balance >= amount)
    {
       balance -= amount;
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You can't withdraw money that you don't have!");
       // or else you could charge an overdraft fee as long as you're within 
       // a certain tolerance (minimum of -1000 or something like that). 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create the account:

```
Checking Account ca = new Checking Account (John, Smith, 123456, 0);
```

To deposit $250:

```
ca.deposit(250);
```

To withdraw $98:

```
ca.withdraw(98);
```

Business Logic:

```
public void deposit(decimal amount)
{
    balance += amount;
}
public void withdraw(decimal amount)
{
    balance -= amount;
}
```

As the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211826/1121302) states, it is wise to validate scenarios such as overdrawing or withdrawing when you have no money (or less) in your account!

---

BONUS:

You can also write a GetBalance function to verify deposits/withdrawals.

```
public decimal GetBalance(long accountNumber)
{
    return balance;
}
```

And call it using:

```
var currentBalance = ca.GetBalance(123456);
```

Comment: Excellent. You guys are the best. Seriously.